# Http Servlet request thread hangs --App server is Tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

Http Servlet request thread hangs(Tomcat. )
What will happen to this thread when my proxy server closes the connection with the tomcat. 
Who will kill that thread?

Also is there an efficient way to manage the http Request threads with request timeouts.

I also tried to use StuckThreadDetectionValve to get Stuck threads. But it dint help me much. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you saying that you have a stuck thread and you're wondering how it will get cleaned up? You can implement a timeout process in Tomcat that will kill threads longer than a specified timeout. However, it's *usually* best to handle this in your application yourself (so that you can gracefully kill the process or stop whatever you're doing). Really, though, you should aim to figure out _why_ it is hanging, and solve that instead.

Comment: Yes. I have a stuck thread and im wondering who will clean it up . I cannot solve it as it is depending up on some external services.

Comment: **I also tried to use StuckThreadDetectionValve to get Stuck threads. But it dint help me much** - Can you please be a bit specific? Also what does you application do with this request, I mean do you have async requests? What tomcat & Servlet version are you using?

Comment: My application calls another server using httpclient. Also StuckThreadDetection valves can print the threads that are stuck . (you can also specify the time) . Tomcat is 7 .